# Normalizing series for plotting in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that I would like to plot, generated by the following code.

```
df_rn1 = as.data.frame(cbind(rnorm(40, 1, 1), rep("rn1", 40)))
df_rn2 = as.data.frame(cbind(rnorm(40, 10, 1), rep("rn2", 40)))
df_rn3 = as.data.frame(cbind(rnorm(40, 100, 1), rep("rn3", 40)))

df_test = rbind(df_rn1, df_rn2, df_rn3)
colnames(df_test) <- c("value", "type")
```

I would like to plot the dataframe normalized by the respective first observation s.t. they are scaled properly. However, I am not getting further than this:

```
ggplot(aes(x = rep(1:40, 3), y=as.numeric(as.character(value)), color = type), data = df_test) +
      geom_line()
```

Is it possible to do the normalization by types directly in the ggplot code?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
library(tidyverse);
df_test %>%
    group_by(type) %>%
    mutate(
        value = as.numeric(as.character(value)),
        value.scaled = (value - mean(value)) / sd(value),
        idx = 1:n()) %>%
    ggplot(aes(idx, value.scaled, colour = type)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Note that values are scaled *within `type`*; not sure what you're after, for global scaling, see @ManishSaraswat's answer.

Comment: Hi, yes. I meant scaling within type

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scale` function to normalize the values.

```
df_test %>% 
    mutate(value = scale(value)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = rep(1:40, 3), y = value, color=type))+
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks, but the result should be by type rn1, rn2, rn3. See the color in the aes above.